# Incorrect Syntax multi part identifier

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Currently I'm getting an incorrect syntax but can't locate its origins. Any thoughts on what i'm missing. Multi-part identifier pvxme.mt couldn't be found.

```
SELECT
    PVXME.MT
    PVXME.MT_VERSION
    PVXME.START_DATE_LOCAL
    PVXMEDS.CREATION_DATE_LOCAL
    PVXMIHS.USER_NAME
    PVXMEDE.PAT_ID
    PVXMEDE.STRING_VALUE
    PVXMEDE.NUM_VALUE AS MEDE_NUM_VALUE
    RVXMIIF2.II
    RVXMIIF2.NUM_VALUE AS MIIF_NUM_VALUE;
FROM 
    PVXMEDE
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    PVXMEDG ON PVXMEDG.ME = PVXMEDE.ME;
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    PVXMEDG ON PVXMEDG.SEQUENCE = PVXMEDE.SEQUENCE 
            AND PVXMEDG.SOURCE_TP = PVXMEDE.SOURCE_TP 
            AND PVXMEDG.SOURCE_ID = PVXMEDE.SOURCE_ID 
            AND PVXMEDG.SOURCE_VERSION = PVXMEDE.SOURCE_VERSION;
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    PVXMEDS ON PVXMEDS.ME = PVXMEDG.ME 
            AND PVXMEDS.SEQUENCE=PVXMEDG.SEQUENCE;
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    PVXME ON PVXME.ME = PVXMEDS.ME AND PVXME.MT=;
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    PVXMI ON PVXMI.MI = PVXME.MI;
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    PVXMIHS ON PVXMIHS.MI = PVXME.MI;
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    PVXMIID ON PVXME.ME = PVXMIID2.ME;
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    RVXMIII ON PVXMIID2.MI = RVXMIIF2.MI 
            AND PVXMIID2.ID = RVXMIIF2.ID 
            AND PVXMIID2.ID_SEQUENCE = RVXMIIF2.ID_SEQUENCE 
            AND PVXMIID2.ME = RVXMIIF2.ME;
WHERE
    (PVXMIHS.USER_NAME <> 'sipat'
    AND PVXMIHS.WHAT = 'MethodPrepare'
    AND PVXME.CX_STRING_4  =  '20190117-7h40m'
    AND PVXME.MT  LIKE  'MK-0431%Tab CA%'
    AND PVXMEDE.PAT_ID  NOT LIKE  '%Spectrum')
    AND (RVXMIIF2.II  =  'LeverageLimit'OR RVXMIIF2.II  =  'XresidualLimit')
```

Comment: Please post the query **as formatted TEXT** - do **NOT** post screenshots of code! This is quite annoying and not well received on SO .....

Comment: @marc_s. Sorry about this. I've updated my posting.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, ***PLEASE*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Two things jump out - do you **really** want to use semicolons after each JOIN condition? (`RIGHT OUTER JOIN PVXMEDG ON PVXMEDG.ME = PVXMEDE.ME;`) I'm not sure how SQL Server likes that..... and this JOIN condition is definitely **incomplete**: `RIGHT OUTER JOIN PVXME ON PVXME.ME = PVXMEDS.ME AND PVXME.MT=; ` (and that's probably one of the errors you're getting)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- **do put** a colon after each column in the `SELECT` list of columns
- do **NOT** put a semicolon at the end of the list of columns and of each `JOIN` condition
- do complete the `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` that references `PVXME.MT =` .......

Code:

```
SELECT
    PVXME.MT,
    PVXME.MT_VERSION,
    PVXME.START_DATE_LOCAL,
    PVXMEDS.CREATION_DATE_LOCAL,
    PVXMIHS.USER_NAME,
    PVXMEDE.PAT_ID,
    PVXMEDE.STRING_VALUE,
    PVXMEDE.NUM_VALUE AS MEDE_NUM_VALUE,
    RVXMIIF2.II,
    RVXMIIF2.NUM_VALUE AS MIIF_NUM_VALUE
FROM 
    PVXMEDE
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    PVXMEDG P1 ON P1.ME = PVXMEDE.ME    -- use table alias P1 here
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    PVXMEDG P2 ON P2.SEQUENCE = PVXMEDE.SEQUENCE  -- use table alias P2 here
               AND P2.SOURCE_TP = PVXMEDE.SOURCE_TP 
               AND P2.SOURCE_ID = PVXMEDE.SOURCE_ID 
               AND P2.SOURCE_VERSION = PVXMEDE.SOURCE_VERSION
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    PVXMEDS ON PVXMEDS.ME = P2.ME 
            AND PVXMEDS.SEQUENCE = P2.SEQUENCE
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    PVXME ON PVXME.ME = PVXMEDS.ME AND PVXME.MT = ?????? -- ** COMPLETE THIS! **
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    PVXMI ON PVXMI.MI = PVXME.MI
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    PVXMIHS ON PVXMIHS.MI = PVXME.MI
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    PVXMIID ON PVXME.ME = PVXMIID2.ME
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    RVXMIII ON PVXMIID2.MI = RVXMIIF2.MI
            AND PVXMIID2.ID = RVXMIIF2.ID 
            AND PVXMIID2.ID_SEQUENCE = RVXMIIF2.ID_SEQUENCE 
            AND PVXMIID2.ME = RVXMIIF2.ME
WHERE
    (PVXMIHS.USER_NAME <> 'sipat'
    AND PVXMIHS.WHAT = 'MethodPrepare'
    AND PVXME.CX_STRING_4  =  '20190117-7h40m'
    AND PVXME.MT  LIKE  'MK-0431%Tab CA%'
    AND PVXMEDE.PAT_ID  NOT LIKE  '%Spectrum')
    AND (RVXMIIF2.II  =  'LeverageLimit'OR RVXMIIF2.II  =  'XresidualLimit')
```

Comment: I'm getting an invalid object name for pvxmede. Any thoughts?

Comment: Now I'm getting: Msg 1013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The objects "PVXMEDG" and "PVXMEDG" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

Comment: @Diego83; you're joining against `PVXMEDG` twice - therefore, you need to use **table alias** to keep these two apart (I added the aliases `P1` and `P2` to my query)

Comment: I'm getting some performance hits now. Msg 1105, Level 17, State 2, Line 1
Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage:  140738207350784' in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.    Any thoughts on fine-tuning?